# Drawing lines for Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am kind of new to all this and cannot seem to figure out how to make a for loop (if possible) that will draw the type of line I am looking for.  I am trying to create an image of a pumpkin using canvas and want to outline the teeth.  I was hoping there was an easier way than typing out all of the code to draw the individual lines it takes to outline the teeth.  Here is the code for each individual line, but I cannot seem to figure out the for loop that would do the same thing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = '#cc5200';
context.moveTo(220, 590);
context.lineTo(220, 550);
context.moveTo(220, 550);
context.lineTo(260, 550);
context.moveTo(260, 550);
context.lineTo(260, 590);
context.moveTo(260, 590);
context.lineTo(300, 590);
context.moveTo(300, 590);
context.lineTo(300, 550);
context.moveTo(300, 550);
context.lineTo(340, 550);
context.moveTo(340, 550);
context.lineTo(340, 590);
context.moveTo(340, 590);
context.lineTo(380, 590);
context.moveTo(380, 590);
context.lineTo(380, 550);
context.moveTo(380, 550);
context.lineTo(420, 550);
context.moveTo(420, 550);
context.lineTo(420, 590);
context.moveTo(420, 590);
context.lineTo(460, 590);
context.moveTo(460, 590);
context.lineTo(460, 550);
context.moveTo(460, 550);
context.lineTo(500, 550);
context.moveTo(500, 550);
context.lineTo(500, 590);
context.moveTo(500, 590);
context.lineTo(540, 590);
context.moveTo(540, 590);
context.lineTo(540, 550);
context.moveTo(540, 550);
context.lineTo(580, 550);
context.lineTo(580, 590);

context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a start:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = '#cc5200';

// Example line that is repeated in the loop
context.moveTo(10, 90);      // Bottom left
context.lineTo(10, 50);      // Up
context.lineTo(10 + 40, 50); // Right
context.lineTo(10 + 40, 90); // Down
context.lineTo(10 + 80, 90); // Right

context.moveTo(220, 90);
for (var i = 220; i <= 540; i += 80) {
  context.lineTo(i, 90);
  context.lineTo(i, 50);
  context.lineTo(i + 40, 50);
  context.lineTo(i + 40, 90);
  if(i != 540) // Don't draw the line for the last one
    context.lineTo(i + 80, 90);
}


context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

`x` values of `580` aside, you seem to be drawing 2 lines for each `x` coordinate, 40 pixels apart. Those steps can be put into a loop.

Comment: Thanks, but that gave me zig-zag lines instead of squared lines.  I did find a for loop that does grid lines for the whole canvas but can't seem to figure out how to modify it to only draw the given lines and not get a zig-zag pattern.

Comment: @BrandyKimmel: I've edited the answer. The `lineTo(10` lines are just to draw an example of the repeating pattern, those can be removed. :-)

Comment: That is more like it, now I just have to figure out how to get it all moved down lol.  Thank you.

Comment: @BrandyKimmel: The `50` and `90` in there are `y` coordinates. Make them higher, and the line will go down.

Comment: I did take notice to that.  Thank you very much for your help.